# how to make a perfect Layout for different Screen sizes that uses multiple ImageViews with different sources?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, imageview, android-linearlayout

How do I make a Layout that shows Multiple ImageViews with Different image-sources of different size, to appear perfectly on different screens i.e 5" or 5.2" or 3.7".
I'm working on a Linear layout
here is part of my layout file.

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="270dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/delhiie">
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="270dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/kolkatai"
                    android:id="@+id/iv2"
                    android:clickable="true">
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="270dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/mumbaii"
                    android:id="@+id/iv4"
                    android:clickable="true">
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="270dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/chennaii">
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

And here is the preview for different Screens:
[for 5.2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs5yl.png)
[for 3.7"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK9ad.png)

Comment: Check the documentation on this topic: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html